# Rigorous Definition of Sigma Notation for Sums

Tags: summation, recursion

I'm trying to come up with a rigorous way to define sums using sigma notation. Obviously$^{1}$, the sum $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$ needs to be defined on a set $X$ on which we have previously defined an addition $+$, and it needs to be defined recursively for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ as
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{0}a_{i}&=0,
\\
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}a_{i}&=\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right)+a_{n+1}.
\end{align*}
What I'm struggling with are the details... What's the proper way to define the terms $a_{i}$? First, I was thinking about stating "Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be a set and let $(a_{i})_{i\in I}$ be a sequence in $X$,'' but then kinda dismissed this idea because we want to define $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, not just for a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. I'm also having concerns about dropping the requirement that $I\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and using $(a_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ instead. Then I considered to state "Let $\{\text{$a_{i}\in A\mid a_{1}\leq a_{i}\leq a_{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$}\}$'' but have similar concerns with this formulation. Also some text state that there are issues with infinite sums, guess it has to do with the Axiom of Choice, so I started questioning if we can actually define $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ at all.

---

$^{1}$ <sub>I know, we should never use terms like "obviously" when trying to do rigorous math...</sub>

Comment: $a_i$ is just a notation for $a(i)$, where $a:\mathbb{N}\to X$. What's the problem here?

Comment: If we're using a sequence $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$, shouldn't we be talking about a sequence $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$ instead of a sequence $a:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$?

Comment: or would $\sum: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$ be more accurate?

Comment: Where would choice be used? Wherever addition is defined repeated addition can be, and is, defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cartesian product of sets is most convenient here. If you have $+: X \times X \to X$ defined (denoted $(a_1, a_2) \mapsto a_1 + a_2$), then we would define $\Sigma^n: X^n \to X$ to be $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto x_1 + (x_2 + (\cdots  + (x_{n - 1} + x_n))$. Then if we have an $n$-tuple $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in X^n$ we can define $$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i := \Sigma^n(a_1, \dots, a_n).$$
The $n$ was arbitrary so this construction works for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Notice that we needed very few assumptions on $+$ so this can be applied very generally.

Comment: I kinda like the idea of using iteration for this, and it would actually align with the usual recursive definition given in my initial post...

Comment: Couldn't we also define $f:X^{n}\rightarrow X$ instead of $\Sigma^{n}:X^{n}\rightarrow X$ and then define $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}:=f (x_{1},\dots, x_{n})$ instead of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}:=\sum\limits^{n}(a_{1},\dots, a_{n})$ or is that upper index $n$ and use of $\sum$ instead of $f$ necessary?

Comment: After reflecting about my own question I think we actually wanna keep the upper index $n$ because $\sum^{n}$ (or $f^{n}$) is an iteration?

Comment: I just chose the notation to be suggestive. You can call it whatever you'd like and it would get the point across.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help :)